# NDK vs Java: is there a difference in access to API?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-sdk-tools

My previous question was marked as duplicate and linked to a question that was too general and whose answers were scattered and unfocused.

I'm not asking about development time or runtime speed or memory footprint.

Is there ANY difference in API or OS access between NDK and Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a huge difference. There are quite a lot of things you cannot do in NDK directly, and you must call Java methods that will invoke OS API. There are also APIs that are available only in NDK, but the NDK is much more limited. You can see a brief summary here: [Android NDK Native APIs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html).

BUT - why are you addressing this in a general manner? You should be examining you specific need, your system requirements, and see if you can benefit from using the NDK.

Comment: I have legacy C++ code and if I can use the NDK I must

Comment: I don't see where in that link it explicitly states that there some things I can't do with NDK.

Comment: I did not say it shows the difference, it shows a summary of the NDK native API. I told you there are things you cannot do from my experience...

Comment: give me high level examples.

Comment: yakobom did not say there are things you cannot do in NDK. He only explained that there are many things that your C++ code can only achieve by calling Java API. This means that these parts of your project will not stay platform neutral.

Comment: I do not think you can create and manage the UI, for example. Also, I think you cannot use OpenGL directly without any Java code. Also, NDK code will be much longer and complicated and harder to debug. You may consider a hybrid application, that uses the code you have in NDK, and utilizes other Java code where possible.

Comment: @yakobom doesn't every Android app have to be a Java app by default and then wrap NDK-specific code?